# UTC <-> PST Inconsistent Behavior Around Spring Time Change?

Tags: postgresql, timezone, dbeaver

Using postgres 14, I'm trying to add timezone info to timestamps that came to me without and I'm noticing a weird behavior around the March time change across multiple years. The PST timestamps are unique. The 03:00 time duplicates in my timestamps converted to UTC, as if UTC was undergoing a +1 hour time change. The 02:00 hour was missing in UTC.

```
SELECT 
     start_ppt::timestamp,
     start_ppt::timestamp at time zone 'US/Pacific' as start_tz,
     start_ppt::timestamp at time zone 'US/Pacific' at time zone 'UTC' as start_utc2
from table
```

| start_ppt | start_tz | start_utc2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-03-09 15:00:00.000 | 2019-03-09 18:00:00.000 -0500 | 2019-03-09 23:00:00.000 |
| 2019-03-09 16:00:00.000 | 2019-03-09 19:00:00.000 -0500 | 2019-03-10 00:00:00.000 |
| 2019-03-09 17:00:00.000 | 2019-03-09 20:00:00.000 -0500 | 2019-03-10 01:00:00.000 |
| 2019-03-09 18:00:00.000 | 2019-03-09 21:00:00.000 -0500 | **2019-03-10 03:00:00.000** |
| 2019-03-09 19:00:00.000 | 2019-03-09 22:00:00.000 -0500 | **2019-03-10 03:00:00.000** |
| 2019-03-09 20:00:00.000 | 2019-03-09 23:00:00.000 -0500 | 2019-03-10 04:00:00.000 |
| 2019-03-09 21:00:00.000 | 2019-03-10 00:00:00.000 -0500 | 2019-03-10 05:00:00.000 |
| 2019-03-09 22:00:00.000 | 2019-03-10 01:00:00.000 -0500 | 2019-03-10 06:00:00.000 |
| 2019-03-09 23:00:00.000 | 2019-03-10 03:00:00.000 -0400 | 2019-03-10 07:00:00.000 |
| 2019-03-10 00:00:00.000 | 2019-03-10 04:00:00.000 -0400 | 2019-03-10 08:00:00.000 |
| 2019-03-10 01:00:00.000 | 2019-03-10 05:00:00.000 -0400 | 2019-03-10 09:00:00.000 |
| 2019-03-10 03:00:00.000 | 2019-03-10 06:00:00.000 -0400 | 2019-03-10 10:00:00.000 |
| 2019-03-10 04:00:00.000 | 2019-03-10 07:00:00.000 -0400 | 2019-03-10 11:00:00.000 |

Edit:
US/New York offset change happens at 2019-03-10 07:00:00.000 UTC

US/Pacific offset change happens at 2019-03-10 10:00:00.000 UTC

Why would 2019-03-10 03:00:00.000 UTC repeat?

```
select 
    '2019-03-10 02:00:00.000'::timestamp at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'US/Pacific' as sample_utc_2019,
    '2019-03-09 18:00:00.000'::timestamp at time zone 'US/Pacific' at time zone 'UTC' as sample_pst_2019,
    '2023-03-12 02:00:00.000'::timestamp at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'US/Pacific' as sample_utc_2023,
    '2023-03-11 18:00:00.000'::timestamp at time zone 'US/Pacific' at time zone 'UTC' as sample_pst_2023;
```

| sample_utc_2019 | sample_pst_2019 | sample_utc_2023 | sample_pst_2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-03-09 18:00:00.000 | 2019-03-10 03:00:00.000 | 2023-03-11 18:00:00.000 | 2023-03-12 03:00:00.000 |

I would expect the results of this last query to be

| sample_utc_2019 | sample_pst_2019 | sample_utc_2023 | sample_pst_2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-03-09 18:00:00.000 | 2019-03-10 **02:00:00.000** | 2023-03-11 18:00:00.000 | 2023-03-12 **02:00:00.000** |

What am I missing here? I have tried set timezone = 'UTC' and 'US/Pacific'

Edit: it has something to do with my client (dbeaver using most current postgres drivers). The same 2019-03-10 03:00:00.000 UTC repeat does not happen if the same query is run with psql, psycopg, pgadmin. I have not been able to identify any setting that might control this. Very bizarre, like the dbeaver session is trying to adjust for dst in display when it should just show what's actually there.

Comment: `The PST timestamps are unique` quite the opposite - summer time means that the *local* time is moving +/-1 hour, not UTC. When that happens, you may get two local times that represent the *same* UTC instant, because the local time offset has changed. Or you may get a "missing" hour. `The 02:00 hour was missing in UTC.` no, the equivalent is missing in the Pacific timezone. If time jumps ahead 1 hour at 03:00 to 04:00, it means you won't find any values between `0:300` and `03:59.9999999999999...`

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm still confused why converting from '2019-03-10 02:00:00.000' UTC to PT gets me '2019-03-09 18:00:00.000' but converting from '2019-03-09 18:00:00.000' PT to UTC returns '2019-03-10 03:00:00.000' UTC? The local time offset does not change until  2019-03-10 03:00:00.000 PT, not UTC time, which is reflected in the raw data (skipping 2019-03-10 02:00 PT) The duplicate times you mention happen in November when local time goes back 1.